# Flutter code gives error when using "!" or "?"

Tags: flutter

I'm using the following code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zoom_drawer/flutter_zoom_drawer.dart';

class MenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () => ZoomDrawer.of(context)!.toggle(),
      );
}
```

However, the editor reports error when I use the "!" symbol. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: what about you flutter version

Comment: *What* error? It's practically impossible to help you without knowing exactly what kind of error you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure you have this line of code in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

#### This ensures that you are using the dart SDK with a null safety-enabled version.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Flutter SDK by running 'flutter upgrade' command in terminal.